# How to add an object to a static arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arrayList of type "customer" which im trying to add some objects if same type to.
when i use the add() method I get an error and a red line under that command The code works fine other than that part.

```
public class Admin {
public static ArrayList<Customers> customers = new ArrayList<>();    
Customers owner = new Customers("admin", "admin", 0);
Customers c = new Customers("test","123",0);
customers.add(c); //error is here
customers.add(new Customers("test","123",0)); //tried this one too but it doesnt work either //it says illegal start of type and not package exists }
```

//normal constructor

```
public class Customers {
private String username;
public String password;
private int points;
private String Status;

public Customers(String username, String password, int points ) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.points   = points;
}}
```

Comment: Your code is not inside of a method in `Admin`, it is in the class scope.  The other code works because they are declaring variables which will be interpreted as class fields which would not give an error, but `.add` cannot be used outside of a method.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two points you have to be aware of:

1. Most statements in Java cannot be written outside of methods or static blocks.
2. You need an instance of a class to use non-static fields or methods.

Since `c` is not static, you can use it only in the constructor or a non-static method.

```java
public class Admin {
    ...
    
    public Admin() {
        customers.add(c); // this works
        customers.add(new Customers("test","123",0)); // this works
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        customers.add(c); // this does also work
        customers.add(new Customers("test","123",0)); // this works
    }

    static {
        customers.add(c); // this does not work, because c is non-static
        customers.add(new Customers("test","123",0)); // this works
    }

    public static void someStaticMethod() {
        customers.add(c); // still doesn't work, because c is non-static
        customers.add(new Customers("test","123",0)); // this works
    }
}
```